# React useEffect infinite API calls even with empty array

Tags: reactjs

I have this component, I actually need it to render whenever `components` change, but even with an empty array it just keeps sending `list` requests to the API infinitely.
I'm not very good with React and I'm trying to understand what keeps the useEffect to run again and again

```
useEffect(() => {
    const run = async () => {
        const response = await componentService.list();
        const components = response.map(component => ({
            id: component.id,
            name: component.name,
            image: component.image,
            benefits: component.benefits?.map((benefit, i, benefits) => benefit + (i < benefits.length - 1 ? ' ,' : '')),
            learn_image: component.learn_image,
            learn_text: component.learn_text,
            extra_learn_text: component.extra_learn_text,
            suggestion: component.suggestion,
            family_type: component.family_type,
            properties: component.properties?.map((property, i, properties) => property + (i < properties.length - 1 ? ' ,' : '')),
            nutritional_characteristic: component.nutritional_characteristic,
        }))
        setComponents(components);
    }
    run();
}, []);
```

I've also tried it like this with no luck:

```
useEffect(() => {
    componentService.list().then(res => {
        res.map(component => ({
            id: component.id,
            name: component.name,
            image: component.image,
            benefits: component.benefits?.map((benefit, i, benefits) => benefit + (i < benefits.length - 1 ? ' ,' : '')),
            learn_image: component.learn_image,
            learn_text: component.learn_text,
            extra_learn_text: component.extra_learn_text,
            suggestion: component.suggestion,
            family_type: component.family_type,
            properties: component.properties?.map((property, i, properties) => property + (i < properties.length - 1 ? ' ,' : '')),
            nutritional_characteristic: component.nutritional_characteristic,
        }))
        setComponents(res);
    })
}, []);
```

can you help me figure out what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Using an empty array as a dependency here should be enough to ensure that this code will only run in the first render. What I'd suggest you to do is debug `componentService.list()` as it is responsible for the API calls. If you can share it here maybe we can help

Answer (score -1):

Let me explain for you in an easy way the use of useEffect.

useEffect main use to watch for any changes in the state and do a callback function to do what you want.

but there are 3 cases for using the useEffect Hook that React provides for us.

1- empty dependency on useEffect and that is how it looks

```
useEffect(() => {
 this will execute the callback function just one time after the component 
 render
 and will do the logic you need but just one time.
}, []);
```

2- state in dependency and that how is it looks.

```
useEffect(() => {
 this kind of use is very helpful because what is happening here is as
 long your state is changed the callback function will execute and that kind 
 of use is very helpful if you want to run some logic based on state 
 changes.
}, [state]);
```

3- state with no dependency and that is how it looks.

```
useEffect(() => {
 this will run always after your component render.
});
```

Comment: How could adding dependencies to the hook make the requests to the API be called less often?

Comment: you're right, so in his case, he should to not have problems from using useEffect with no dependency and things should work fine.

Comment: Yes, they might have a problem with this `componentService.list()` that we have no information about. Let's wait and see if they update the post with its details